# ListBuckets operation: Access Denied - aws mfa token

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm struggling to list buckets from python script using my mfa aws account but I get denied every time when I'm running my code.

**output-scripts**

```
Enter your MFA Token:899211
{'Credentials': {'AccessKeyId': 'ASIASUXXXXXXXXXXX', 'SecretAccessKey': 'T1Cn9FpXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXl', 'SessionToken': 'CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC=', 'Expiration': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 22, 10, 0, 21, tzinfo=tzutc())}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '6c05ad08-XXXX-4b2a-XXXX-VVVVVVVVV', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': '6c05ad08-XXXx-XXXX-XXXXXXX-8c4a5b504404', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '804', 'date': 'Wed, 22 Apr 2020 09:00:21 GMT'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws_connect.py", line 23, in <module>
    response_s3 = s3.list_buckets()
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 316, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/my_user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 626, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

**my_script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import json
import subprocess
import os
import boto3

token = input('Enter your MFA Token:')
client = boto3.client('sts')

response = client.get_session_token(
    DurationSeconds=3600,
    SerialNumber='arn:aws:iam::18022222222:mfa/mymfauser',
    TokenCode=token,
)



print(response)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
response_s3 = s3.list_buckets()

# Output the bucket names
print('Existing buckets:')
for bucket in response_s3['Buckets']:
    print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
```

So, I'm getting the right **accesskeyid**, **secretAccesskey** and also the **SesstionToken** but I'm not able to list anything from my account.

Comment: what is the policy attached to your user ? Have you checked the IAM policy and its permissions ?

Comment: Make sure the IAM policy contains : `"s3:GetObject", "s3:ListBucket"`

Comment: I might be wrong but don't you need to use the `response` to set the obtained credentials into the S3 client? Something like

`s3 = boto3.client(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY,
    aws_session_token=SESSION_TOKEN,
)`

Comment: well.. this is not working what you have posted.. I found something weird that it works..If I will export accesskeyid, secretAccesskey, SesstionToken and region into bash system , the s3 buckets can be listed. The variables can pe printed with printenv. If you don't export these variables,you'll not get this to work. Now I have other problem, how can I export variable into bash system via python script, it doesn't work at all. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The MFA session credentials must be passed to `boto3.client('s3')` in order to be used. The easiest way to do this is in the code itself.

For example:

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)
```

And for anyone who gets here and needs to use a different profile from their credentials file, that is done with this line:

```
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='PROFILE_NAME')
```

Last thing to make sure is that the user account has an ALLOW policy for:

```
s3:ListAllMyBuckets
```

Put together, the entire script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import boto3

serial_number = input('Enter your device serial number: ')
token = input('Enter your MFA Token: ')

# This line is necessary if you're using
# a profile other than your default profile
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='demo_cli')

client = boto3.client('sts')

response = client.get_session_token(
    DurationSeconds=3600,
    SerialNumber=serial_number,
    TokenCode=token,
)

s3 = boto3.client('s3',
    aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken']
)

response_s3 = s3.list_buckets()

# Output the bucket names
print('Existing buckets:')
for bucket in response_s3['Buckets']:
    print(f'  {bucket["Name"]}')
```